# QGIS: Plug-in to determine optimal distance between coordinate and shape file

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, distance

I have coordinates of power plants and I would like to determine their optimal distance (shortest distance) to electric grid lines (shape file).

How could this be done in QGIS?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "optimal distance"? Do you mean what's the shortest distance?

Comment: Do not create a duplicat of your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383887/qgis-r-calculating-optimal-distance-between-coordinates but update the older question to add more information. Just click edit to do that. So the closed question be be re-opened.

Comment: That question was also mine and still unanswered. The reason why I posted again is because that one was closed.

Comment: Your question was closed because it needs to be more focused. As I commented, you should provide more information if you expect answers because the question was not yet clear to me. If you just post the same question again with even less information, it risks to be closed as well. Did you take the [tour]? If you edit your old question, it can be re-opened and people can answer.